# sort Key of JSONArray

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json Array like this :

```
[
    {
        "pos1": "Batterie de préchauffage",
        "attributes": [
            {
                "disconnect": "false",
                "disconnectBis": "false"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "pos4": "Batterie haute température",
        "attributes": [
            {
                "test": "true",
                "testBis": "false"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "pos3": "free"
    },
    {
        "pos2": "free"
    }
]
```

How can i Organize my json to have somethign like that :

```
[
    {
        "pos1": "Batterie de préchauffage",
        "attributes": [
            {
                "disconnect": "false",
                "disconnectBis": "false"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "pos2": "Batterie haute température",
        "attributes": [
            {
                "test": "true",
                "testBis": "false"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "pos3": "free"
    },
    {
        "pos4": "free"
    }
]
```

Because i need to have 'pos' in progressive order

I hope someone will understand my problem, and tell me how can i can resolve this..

I have already search and not found the same problem than me..
Thanks a lot

Comment: keys are not intended to work like that, it is possible and I will help you if that's what you want, but let me ask you first. Can't you just add a key with name: "id": 0, "id": 1, etc? otherwise we will have to strip the digits from the object.key which isn't very beautiful :P

Comment: Your objects should have a common name for the identifier property.

Comment: I know that these keys are not beautiful, but in my program it make like that... I will try to change it :x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit late to the party but I don't think the other answers are producing the output you want, i.e. you want to retain the current array order and replace the current `pos[num]` property of the object in the array with `'pos' + (idx + 1)`:

```js
const input = [ { "pos1": "Batterie de préchauffage", "attributes": [ { "disconnect": "false", "disconnectBis": "false" } ] }, { "pos4": "Batterie haute température", "attributes": [ { "test": "true", "testBis": "false" } ] }, { "pos3": "free" }, { "pos2": "free" } ]

const output = input.map((o, idx) => {
  const id = Object.keys(o).find(id => /^pos/.test(id));
  if (id !== `pos${idx + 1}`) {
    o[`pos${idx + 1}`] = o[id];
    delete o[id];
  }
  return o;
});

console.log(output)
```

Comment: it's exactly what i want ! thanks a lot, but maybe i will follow your advices, and change my json

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the first property of the object is what you want to sort by, something as simplistic as this should work:

```js
var array = [
    {
        "pos1": "Batterie de préchauffage",
        "attributes": [
            {
                "disconnect": "false",
                "disconnectBis": "false"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "pos4": "Batterie haute température",
        "attributes": [
            {
                "test": "true",
                "testBis": "false"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "pos3": "free"
    },
    {
        "pos2": "free"
    }
];

var sortedArray = array.sort((a, b) => {
    var nameKeyA = Object.keys(a)[0];
    var nameKeyB = Object.keys(b)[0];
    return nameKeyA > nameKeyB;
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(sortedArray));
```

Comment: Look at the required output again.

Comment: @Andy interesting... I figured that was just a typo from OP. I'm not entirely sure why one would want that as the output.

Answer (score 0):

This will provide you with the output you want. It uses the following JS methods/syntax:

- [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)
- [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)
- [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```js
const json = '[{"pos1":"Batterie de préchauffage","attributes":[{"disconnect":"false","disconnectBis":"false"}]},{"pos4":"Batterie haute température","attributes":[{"test":"true","testBis":"false"}]},{"pos3":"free"},{"pos2":"free"}]';

// Parse the JSON
const arr = JSON.parse(json);

// `map` over the array, grabbing the object and index
const out = arr.map((obj, i) => {

  // Iterate over the keys from each object
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {

    // If a key includes the substring "pos"...
    if (key.includes('pos')) {

      // ...and the new key number doesn't match the current index...
      if (key !== `pos${i + 1}`) {

        // ...copy it to a new key (starting at pos1)...
        obj[`pos${i + 1}`] = obj[key];

        // ...then delete the old key
        delete obj[key];

      }
    }
  });

  // Return the updated object 
  return obj;
});

console.log(out);
```

Comment: it's exactly what i want ! thanks a lot, but maybe i will follow your advices, and change my json :)

Answer (score -1):

If the name is consistently `pos[num]` this will work.

```js
let data = [
    {
        "pos1": "Batterie de préchauffage",
        "attributes": [
            {
                "disconnect": "false",
                "disconnectBis": "false"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "pos4": "Batterie haute température",
        "attributes": [
            {
                "test": "true",
                "testBis": "false"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "pos3": "free"
    },
    {
        "pos2": "free"
    }
];

const sortPredicate = (a, b) => {
  
  let aProp = parseInt(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(a)[0].substring(3));
  let bProp = parseInt(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(b)[0].substring(3));

  return  aProp - bProp;
}

let sortedData = data.sort(sortPredicate);

console.log(sortedData);
```

Comment: Please note I agree with the comments above, it would be better to fix the JSON to have a proper key. It looks like you are recording slot allocation and what is in the slot or if its free.

Answer (score -1):

```js
let x = [
    {
        "pos1": "Batterie de préchauffage",
        "attributes": [
            {
                "disconnect": "false",
                "disconnectBis": "false"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "pos4": "Batterie haute température",
        "attributes": [
            {
                "test": "true",
                "testBis": "false"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "pos3": "free"
    },
    {
        "pos2": "free"
    }
];

function getPosKey(obj) {
  const firstMatch = Object.keys(obj).find(k => /pos[0-9]+/.test(k));
  return firstMatch;
}

const ordered_keys = x.map(o => getPosKey(o)).sort();
x = x.map((o, idx) => {
  const k = getPosKey(o);
  if(k && ordered_keys[idx] && k !== ordered_keys[idx]) {
    o[ordered_keys[idx]] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(o[k]));
    delete o[k];
  }
  return o;
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(x, null, 2));
```